# Manual multi-dim array key setting via square brackets not working as intended

Tags: arrays, php

Sorry if the title of the question is not exact enough. I recently moved all of my production stuff to a new production server (it used to be just a localhost deal).

The issue is quite a bit of my array work no longer works.

I used to be able to do something along these lines:

```
$arrtest = array();
$arrtest[1]="a";
$arrtest[1][2]="b";
var_dump($arrtest);
```

**output**:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [2]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
}
```

Which would be the same as:

```
$foo = array(1=>'a',array(2=>'b'));
```

However, the square brackets are no longer "assuming" an array. Here is the new production example:

```
$arrtest = array();
$arrtest[1]="a";
$arrtest[1][2]="b";
var_dump($arrtest);
```

**output**:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "a b"
}
```

I assume I am missing a silly setting in php.ini? I can't find what I'm looking for because I'm not sure how to word the question.

**EDIT**
Real World Example since even my question itself is confusing.

```
foreach($mans as $key2=>$val2){
$models = scandir($level1.'/'.$val2);
    foreach($models as $key3=>$val3){
        if(substr($val3,0,1)==='.'){
            unset($models[$key3]);
        }
            $mans[$key2][]=$models[$val3];
    }
}
```

Pretty much about to re-write the entire thing at this point.

Trying to scan a top directoy and grab the folder names (held in $mans)
then go through each directory of $mans recursivly and add it's directories under $mans[$key] as a second level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some funky logic going on. There's no way your first example can ever result in the first output.

You're setting $arrtest[1] to a string, but then you try to a set it as an array. Which is it?

```
$arrtest = array();
// You need to initialize the array here
$arrtest[1]=array();
$arrtest[1][]="a";
$arrtest[1][2]="b";
var_dump($arrtest);
```

This example matches your original output:

```
$arrtest = array();
// You need to initialize the array here
$arrtest[1]="a";
$arrtest[][2]="b";
var_dump($arrtest);
```

As does:

```
$arrtest = array();
// You need to initialize the array here
$arrtest[1]="a";
$arrtest[2][2]="b";
var_dump($arrtest);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [2]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
}
```

Comment: Never had to do that before, is this something new or could I be thinking of something else? It used to assume [] would already initialize the array. Just using `$arr[];` would initialize $arr as an array.

Comment: It could be a difference in PHP versions, but I've tried your code in two different prod environments and it matches what your prod environment is doing. Think about it, is $arrtest[1] a string or an array? You're trying to use it as both. This is close to what you're doing: http://codepad.org/vsXT9OiL The first element of the array is a string, the 2nd is an array.

Comment: for example if I wanted to go through a loop, and do `$arr[]=$someval` then $arr would hold each instance of the loop as an array value. In the current prod server this is not the case, it fatal errors out on `[]`

Comment: You're not doing that though, you're setting $arr[1] twice. Once as a string, then as an array. Check out my 2nd example. I think that's what you're trying to do as it matches your output.

Comment: $arrtest[1][2]="b"; is setting the 2nd character in the $arrtest[1] string. If you set it to [3] instead of [2] you'll get `"a  b"` with  two spaces between them.

Comment: I just made an edit, however the more I explain the question the more frustrating and confusing it becomes.

Comment: Let me explain it another way, lets say I have a folder named "a" and inside of the "a" folder I have a folder named "b" so on and so fourth. I would like to spit out the array we were talking about earlier where the array is array('a',array('b')); and I cant get it to work bassicly

Comment: Did you see the recursive examples in the user notes on http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php?

Comment: that solves that, but I'm still curious why $arr[] does not initiate an array.

Comment: `$arr[] = 'something'` *does* initialize an array, if `$arr` *is not already a string*!!